# How can I send an image from an ImageView in one activity to an ImageButton in another activity. Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to modify an image of an ImageView in one activity using a spinner, and then send that image to an ImageButton in another activity.

Here is the code of the ImageView activity:

```
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent imgIntent = getIntent();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.brown);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
                    imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.blue);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                    imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.black);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
                    imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.white);
                    break;

                default:
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.brown);
                    imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.brown);
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Here is the code of the ImageButton activity:

```
    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
    Intent imgIntent = getIntent();
    imgBtn.setImageResource(imgIntent.getIntExtra("image"));
```

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Full code of MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
    Intent imgIntent = getIntent();
    imgBtn.setImageResource(imgIntent.getIntExtra("image", 0));
    startActivity(imgIntent);

    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomizeDoggo.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Did you start the second activity using that intent you created with                     imgIntent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.white); ?

Comment: imgIntent is not sent from what you have posted, maybe something is missing?

Comment: @WenChao I think I did... didn't I use "Intent imgIntent = getIntent(); I think the issue right now is the "imgBtn.setImageResource(imgIntent.getIntExtra("image")); because Android Studio is finding an error with that.

Comment: are u passing any data in intent from other activity to ImageActivity: Intent imgIntent = getIntent();

Comment: @WenChao wait how is it not sent? Didn't I use putExtra to send the image?

Comment: No, you should start the second activity with that intent, like this "startActivity(imgIntent)"

Comment: @WenChao Like this:        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
        Intent imgIntent = getIntent();
        startActivity(imgIntent);
        imgBtn.setImageResource(imgIntent.getIntExtra("image")); I dont see how that changes anything?

Comment: You said in your question "and then send that image to an ImageButton in another activity", how did you start that activity?

Comment: @WenChao It is my MainActivity that I am sending the image to the ImageButton in.  I will add the whole code to my orifinal post.

Answer (score 0):

just change this line.You haven't passed the default value

```
imgBtn.setImageResource(imgIntent.getIntExtra("image",0));
```

and u haven't started the activity

```
startActivity(mIntent);
```

**UPDATE**
Start an intent like this

```
//This line is missing in your code 
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityToOpen.class);
intent.putExtra("image",id of selected image);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: When I do this the ImageButton image is now blank, and it still does not respond to my spinner selection.

Comment: is your image changing on selecting spinner item?

Comment: It changes in the Activity with my ImageView but I cannot get the transfer to work to the other activity that has the ImageButton. Also, I have not yet implemented code to make the ImageView change permanent, but I'll figure that out later.

Comment: see if you want to pass the selected image than start an intent,see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, but there is no id of selected image, because I want it to choose the one that was selected from the spinner, so do I just enter 0?

Answer (score 0):

In dest Activity:
call `getArgurment()` in `onCreate()` method to get bundle, then `getIntExtra("image",default value);`

Comment: getArgument() in activity  to get bundle.Are u sure??

Comment: yes, i'm sure. i guess you use bundleSavedInstance to get it? realy? i just guess

Comment: sorry sir, i have a misstake: i meant getIntent()

Answer (score 0):

wait try this will surely work

In main activity while starting new activity use this code instead of yours

```
Intent=new Intent(mContext,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.blue);
startActivity(intent);
```

now in second activity in oncreate use this code

```
int image=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image",0);
mPlayPauseImageButton.setImageResource(image);
```